# classless address block from the block adress

Tags: networking, ip-address

Consider the following classless address block:
154.78.177.3/27
List the addresses from this block that would be used as:

a)  the network address, 
b)  the direct broadcast address, and
c)  the range available for hosts to use

Show the steps you took to arrive at your answers.

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) for how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

154.78.177.3/27 means that this ip address is having network address to be 27 bit long ( most significant bit). i.e if we consider the ip address to be 32 bit long. So, in 154.78.177.00000011 ( last 3 number is represented as binary for simplicity) upto 154.78.177.000 (8+8+8+3 = 27) is network address and remaining 5 bit (00000) is for host ip addresses.

Note- 
Network address is the first ip address of the total ip's of host.
Direct broadcast address is the last ip address of total ip's of host.

So final conclusion:
1. Network address is 154.78.177.0. This is calculated by setting all 5 bits of host id to 0.
2. Direct broadcast address is 154.78.177.31. This is calculated by setting all 5 bits of host to 1.
3. Range available for host is from 1 to 30 in the last octect. I.e from 154.78.177.1 to 154.78.177.30 ( As first and last ip is reserved for network address and direct broadcast address respectively)

Comment: Thanx bro for the help